# joomla submenu management

Tags: php, joomla

While using joomla i have section department and cdepartment,edepartment are the department names,then i have to show department in the main menu and names in the sub

Answer (score 1):

create menu for department.

Then create menus for others `cdepartment,edepartment`, and set `Parent Item` to  department menu.